# Change background color depend by value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I will try to best explain my problem and try to find solution. My table have cell called Status, i need to add code that swtich td class depend by value, if question is open add class open `<td class='open'></td>`, if quesiton is on hold add class onHold `<td class='onHold'></td>`... Where from i get thet values? From database, so code look like this:

```
<tbody class="list-group-item-success"> // DEFAULT COLOR IS GREEN
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['questionStatus'] ?></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Default color of cell's is GREEN because when question is posted, default is open, till administrator change to hold or closed or pending. So point is next add some code into that `<td class=" HERE "></td>` i think best is short javascript which will be defined by value of question status if closed add class green or add class red which i will define in css file. If u need more information about this, write me.

Thanks all

Comment: What is wrong with the approach you suggested? `<td class="status-<?php echo $row['questionStatus'] ?>">` or something of the sort? Then just assign a color to each `status-_____` in  your CSS.

Comment: I need to change background color of cell depend by value, so if value is closed add to td class closed which is defined in css file by class .closed... Im i right? @TylerRoper

Comment: Correct. However, I'd just put `status-` before it, but that's personal preference. Ie, `.status-closed { color: red; }`, `.status-open { color: green; }` etc.

Comment: Can you example me code of that because i did't understand u very good? @TylerRoper

Comment: I gave you example code... `<td class="status-<?php echo $row['questionStatus'] ?>">` in your page, and then `.status-closed { color: red; }` in your CSS.

Comment: Don't work... Problem is next, i need to define value of cell if Open define class open else if Closed define class closed @TylerRoper

Comment: That is exactly what the code I posted does... It adds the class `status-closed` for closed items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is not need to create an if/else statements, if your possible values for

```
$row['questionStatus']
```

are:

```
'closed', 'open' and 'onHold' (any other word without spaces)
```

the only thing that you need to do is create css class with these names example:

```
.status-opened, .status-closed, .status-onHold
```

and then you need to implement it this way

```
<td class="status-<?php echo $row['questionStatus'] ?>">
```

so the final render when $row['questionStatus'] got resolve regarding the value will be :

```
<td class="status-opened">
<td class="status-closed">
<td class="status-onHold">
```

if you want to change the background without the need to reload the page, you will need to use JS stuff, I can give you an example as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a switch-statement:

```
<?php
 switch($row['questionStatus']){
  case 'this': $class = 'this'; break;
  case 'that': $class = 'that'; break;
  default:     $class = 'dflt';
 }
?>
```

and output the $class-var within the class-attribute

```
<tbody class="something <?php echo $class ?>">
```

Don't forget to define the css-classes.

Open/Close simple example:

```
<?php

 $class = 'closed';
 if($row['questionStatus'] == 'open'){
  $class = 'open';
 }
```

The rest is the same.

Comment: Don't working... Is there any solution example if value = open add class = open else add class = closed?

Comment: I added a "simple" example for open/close.

Comment: I write this code, and problem is next i have exampel 5 question and all 5 question is marked as closed ( red background ) and i have 4 open and 1 closed...